# How to encode list of numbers as base64

Tags: python, base64

I have a list containing negative numbers, and want to encode the list with base64. How can I do that?

I tried:

```
l = [-10, -48, 100, -20]
bytes(l)
```

But I get the error:

```
ValueError: bytes must be in range(0, 256)
```

I expect the same output as my Java code:

```java
byte[] bytes = {-10, -48, 100, -20};
String result = Base64Utils.encodeToUrlSafeString(bytes);
System.out.println(result); // 9tBk7A==
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error arises because Python expects unsigned 8-bit data, which can be obtained with the modulo `%` operation:

`unsigned == signed % 2 ** num_bits`

```
import base64


def to_unsigned(x, num_bits=8):
    uplim_uint = 2 ** num_bits
    return x % uplim_uint


l = [-10, -48, 100, -20]
base64.b64encode(bytes(to_unsigned(x) for x in l))
# b'9tBk7A=='
```

This can also be hard-coded for performance:

```
l = [-10, -48, 100, -20]
base64.b64encode(bytes(x % 64 for x in l))
# b'9tBk7A=='
```

---

To convert this back you need loop through `base64.b64decode()` and convert the unsigned data back to signed reverting the `%` with a ternary conditional operator:

`signed == unsigned if unsigned < 2 ** (num_bits - 1) else unsigned - 2 ** num_bits`

```
def to_signed(x, num_bits=8):
    half = 2 ** (num_bits - 1)
    uplim_uint = 2 * half
    return x if x < half else x - uplim_uint


[to_signed(x) for x in base64.b64decode(b'9tBk7A==')]
# [-10, -48, 100, -20]
```

or, hard-coding the function:

```
[(x if x < 128 else x - 256) for x in base64.b64decode(b'9tBk7A==')]
# [-10, -48, 100, -20]
```

Comment: How do you decode this back to the original list?

Comment: @SamiAl-Subhi see updates